# The Button on the View will not work after push and then present an UIViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have make a View controller with a button on the navigation bar. And the button works OK now. but after push an UIViewController with animation and then present another UIViewController and then back to Home ViewController, the button on the navigation bar will not work.

if set all the animated to NO when user the method `[ pushViewController: animated:]`, it will work.
  (I'm in the f**king CHINA, Stackoverflow can not work properly, I can not post code here in the right format. Please down load my code [here](https://github.com/bohanyzu/PresentViewControllerTest). https://github.com/bohanyzu/PresentViewControllerTest)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never perform more than one animated screen transition at once. It will most likely break the internal state of UIKit. Either push a new screen or present a new screen. Don't do both at once.

Also look for messages in the log. UIKit often (but not always) reports these issues at runtime.

Comment: I want to know the reason

Comment: This is the reason then. If this is happening then the `UINavigationBar`'s internal state is broken which can lead to any kind of weird error.